# Ordering Files in a Listbox Alphabetically and not Numerically

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to add a list of files from a folder to a listbox in a specific order.
At the moment, I sort the files in explorer view based on a numeric tag and then rename each of the files so that they are named a(1).docx, a(2).docx, a(3).docx etc. My problem kicks in when I hit a(10).docx and a(11).docx as the ordering is alphabetic and not numeric. When the files enter the listbox they go in order of a(1), a(10), a(11), a(12) etc.
Is there an easier way to overcome this ordering issue?
See below for code excerpt

```
Private Sub GetFiles(strFolder As String)
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> Chr(92) Then strFolder = strFolder & Chr(92)
    On Error GoTo lbl_Exit:
    sName = Dir$(strFolder)
    Me.ListFiles.Clear          'ListFiles is my listbox
    Do While sName <> ""
        AddItems Me.ListFiles, sName, strFolder
        sName = Dir$
    Loop
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see the problem solved is to just name the docx-files a(01), a(02) etc. This way your code works as intended. At least for me ;)

Markus

OK, so here's the code i came up with if the renaming is not an option:

```
Private Sub GetFiles(strFolder As String)

    Dim DirArray() As Variant
    ReDim Preserve DirArray(0 To 0) As Variant

    Me.ListFiles.Clear

    '---- Get the filenames into an array ----
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = Dir$(strFolder)

    Do While sFileName <> vbNullString

        DirArray(UBound(DirArray)) = sFileName

        sFileName = Dir$

        If sFileName <> vbNullString Then
            ReDim Preserve DirArray(0 To UBound(DirArray) + 1) As Variant
        End If
    Loop

    '---- Sort the array ----
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim CompareTemp1 As String
    Dim CompareTemp2 As String

    For i = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
        For j = i To UBound(DirArray)

            '---- Compare two neighbouring filename-numbers
            '---- If the one lower in the list has a lower number, they'll be switched around ----
            If GetNumbersFromFileName(CStr(DirArray(j))) < GetNumbersFromFileName(CStr(DirArray(i))) Then

                '---- Change the neighbouring filenames order ----
                CompareTemp1 = DirArray(i)
                CompareTemp2 = DirArray(j)
                DirArray(i) = CompareTemp2
                DirArray(j) = CompareTemp1

           End If
        Next j
    Next i
    '---- Once all this is done, the DirArray should have the desired order, with the undesireables on top ----

    '---- Display the new filename-order in your ListBox ----
    For i = 0 To UBound(DirArray) - 1

        '---- Display only filenames with (##) ----
        If GetNumbersFromFileName(CStr(DirArray(i))) <> -1 Then
            AddItems Me.ListFiles, (CStr(DirArray(i))), strFolder
        End If

    Next i

    ReDim DirArray(0) As Variant

End Sub

Private Function GetNumbersFromFileName(sFileNameToCheck As String) As Integer

    Dim iOpenBracketPosition As Integer
    Dim iClosedBracketPosition As Integer

    '---- Get the bracket-positions ----
    iOpenBracketPosition = InStr(1, sFileNameToCheck, "(")
    iClosedBracketPosition = InStr(1, sFileNameToCheck, ")")

    '---- In case one of the brackets is missing, the file will be pushed to the top ----
    If iOpenBracketPosition = 0 Or iClosedBracketPosition = 0 Then
        GetNumbersFromFileName = -1
        Exit Function
    End If

    '---- Return the Number in between the brackets ----
    GetNumbersFromFileName = CInt(Mid$(sFileNameToCheck, iOpenBracketPosition + 1, iClosedBracketPosition - iOpenBracketPosition - 1))

End Function
```

Hope that makes some sense!
Cheers!
Markus

Comment: that will only work up to a(99), once I hit a(100) that will be sorted after a(10) then a(11) etc... I'd rather not have to prefix multiple 0s to my filenames...

Comment: Got it. Got some code done, that should sort you problem out. Just can't test it right now 'cause I don't have outlook at home. I'll come back to you tomorrow!

Comment: So. The code is there and should work! Hope it helps.

Comment: that took quite a bit of effort thank you! Worked exactly as I wanted, just had to make one small tweak when adding the files to the ListBox

Comment: no problem. i even think this could all be done without the DirArray, using the ListBox itself as the Container for sorting. but well, maybe another time :)